# Why isn't the random integer capped at 20? (Python 3)

Tags: python, python-3.x

When I ran this program

```
print('Welcome to the algebra machine!')
from random import *
a=randint(1,20)
b=(input('Choose a number:'))
c=a*b
print('You got a total of',c)
d=(input('What was the original number?'))
if d==a:
    print('Correct!')
else:
    print('Wrong!')
```

I would get a final answer of, for example, `22222222` if I entered `2`.
Why isn't the `randint` capped at `20`?

Comment: To add to the answers: you may be used to Python 2.x where the `input()` function converts the input to its default type. In Python 3.x, however, the input remains a string. If you want another type, the program needs to do the conversion explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

It *is* capped at 20.  The problem is that you left your input number as a string.  The output you posted, 22222222, is 8 * '2'.  If you want to see 16 as the output, try

```
b = int(input('Choose a number:'))
```

Answer (score 0):

`b` is a String, and anytime you multiply a number by a String, it repeats the string `n` times.

`"2" * 5` returns `"22222"`

Convert `b` to a number before trying to do math on it.